# Bind dns server complains about GeoIP

Tags: 16.04, syslog, bind, geoip

A fresh Ubuntu 16.04 with BIND dns server . Right after starting the bind it logs about GeoIP

Edit1: (3 lines added to beginning )

```
Sep  5 16:11:51 ns3 named[17723]: initializing GeoIP Country (IPv4) (type 1) DB
Sep  5 16:11:51 ns3 named[17723]: GEO-106FREE 20160408 Bu
Sep  5 16:11:51 ns3 named[17723]: initializing GeoIP Country (IPv6) (type 12) DB


Sep  5 16:11:51 ns3 named[17723]: GeoIP City (IPv6) (type 30) DB not available
Sep  5 16:11:51 ns3 named[17723]: GeoIP City (IPv6) (type 31) DB not available
Sep  5 16:11:51 ns3 named[17723]: GeoIP Region (type 3) DB not available
Sep  5 16:11:51 ns3 named[17723]: GeoIP Region (type 7) DB not available
Sep  5 16:11:51 ns3 named[17723]: GeoIP ISP (type 4) DB not available
Sep  5 16:11:51 ns3 named[17723]: GeoIP Org (type 5) DB not available
Sep  5 16:11:51 ns3 named[17723]: GeoIP AS (type 9) DB not available
Sep  5 16:11:51 ns3 named[17723]: GeoIP Domain (type 11) DB not available
Sep  5 16:11:51 ns3 named[17723]: GeoIP NetSpeed (type 10) DB not available
Sep  5 16:11:51 ns3 named[17723]: using default UDP/IPv4 port range: [32768, 60999]
Sep  5 16:11:51 ns3 named[17723]: using default UDP/IPv6 port range: [32768, 60999]
Sep  5 16:11:51 ns3 named[17723]: listening on IPv6 interfaces, port 53
Sep  5 16:11:51 ns3 named[17723]: listening on IPv4 interface lo, 127.0.0.1#53



root@ns3:~#ls -lart /usr/share/GeoIP/
total 5436
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1160739 Apr  9  2016 GeoIP.dat
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 4391541 Apr  9  2016 GeoIPv6.dat
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root    4096 Sep  4 17:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 113 root root    4096 Sep  5 13:55 ..
```

Edit2: I've found that Ubuntu default compile option about GeoIP is like this

```
--with-geoip=/usr
```

How to solve this .

Comment: Related thread: https://lists.isc.org/pipermail/bind-users/2014-July/093479.html

Comment: @ElderGeek So you mean simply "ln -s /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat /var/named/chroot/usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat" will solve the problem ?

Comment: My apologies for any confusion. The related thread contains similar errors (near the beginning of the thread) I make no claim that it will resolve your particular issue. I thought there was a chance it might be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have not paid for the full GeoIP database, you will only have the free subset, and you will receive these messages.

If the lines just before the log excerpt you posted show

```
initializing GeoIP Country (IPv6) (type 12) DB
GEO-106FREE 20160408 Bu
```

then you are successfully using the free database.

The messages are not of concern unless you have paid for the full GeoIP database.

Comment: Thanks . I've edited the log file . So you mean it is not possible to use any GeoIP related stuff with free version ?